How do I create an auto-installer?
This is my first job working in IT and I am still kind of learning the ropes so to speak.
The company I am at has it's own in house software that I am frankly too young to understand. I have installed it many times for users on many different devices and can do basic admin tasks in it fo users, but I do not use it myself nor do I need to. I only need to deploy it to end-user devices. The installers are all hosted on a local server.
For context I am told this is based on an AS400 system. The software also connects to a server.
Main reason I want to automate this install is because I have to do this on every single new user device or even on their KIOSK machines as this is used by nearly everyone. The installation takes a really long time and holds the device hostage from the user. I was told it might be possible to make an MSI file as it uses something called Install Shield, but because there are so many components to the installation I am not finding anything in my research to help guide me.
Any information is appreciated. I have never made a post before so be gentle lol
My process for the installation is as follows:

Open a launch file and say yes as admin then say the installation worked correctly
New window pops up and I click one of the 3 options (always the same one)
After a short install window I navigate to another folder and open a setup.exe
Accept admin and click through the prompts (all the same again)
After install do a restart
Navigate to another folder and basically do the same thing as 3. & 4.(yes there is a launch.exe and 2 setup.exes for this install)
Run a batch file in the main install folder that does some auto-copying of files
Copy files from one folder manually to a temp folder on the C: drive, then re-select the same files and copy again (apparently not doing this can cause some errors with the original location they are copied from), then paste them into the new installed software folder (something like C:\Program Files (x86)\program... etc.)
Click through the prompts (same as always)
Open one of the new files and change some privileges on it so that users can alter their keyboard shortcut preferences.
Open the software and configure said shortcuts
Configure the software to bypass a login prompt so that the user only has to login to one part of it


Nothing about what you've said ties to an IBM i midrange (aka AS/400) .  This sounds like a standard (older) Windows program.    Installshield is still around, it should support a silent install.  But you're going to need to dig into how the Install package is being built.

That is probably where my problem lies. I am not quite sure how to dig for this. I know the steps to take to get it done. I know it creates an IBM folder and that is where the program is found. It is definitely old. I shall continue searching to find out what I can to create a silent installer for this. I figured it wouldn't hurt to make a post just for good measure.

If you have a license for InstallShield, you can also download the InstallShield Standalone Repackager, this application can capture the change you made on a computer with snapshots before and after your changes
